# how to remove reload dropdown in gem wice_grid rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wice-grid

i folowing this tutorial : https://github.com/leikind/wice_grid , the gem generate table but how to relaod dropdown ?

Comment: please help me, need answer

Comment: please show us code or we can't help

Comment: Note: I've never used wice-grid but... from a quick read of the doco, looks like you could plausibly use a "per_page" that is bigger than the number of items you have and that would possibly remove the pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try auto_reload: true

example :

```
g.column name: 'Location', model: 'Location', attribute: 'name', auto_reload: true, custom_filter: :auto do |event|
       event.name
    end
```